# Where are the roasted pepitas?

Tags: glitch-2011

I needed some to make birch candies in order to get another recipe for my sauce pan but I couldn't find them anywhere. I ended up buying 50 from an auction because I couldn't find them in the game. So where do they come from? I thought I saw something that said they came from pumpkins, but I haven't seen any pumpkins either. Apparently they are seasonal as well, but I have been playing since before Halloween, so I don't know what season pumpkins come in except the fall season?

TL;DR Where in the game do roasted pepitas come from?

Comment: Add me as a friend (agent86) and I'll send you whatever I've got.  They're only available around Zilloween.  If you plan on growing pumpkins to make Birch Candies around the holiday, stock up on paper *now* - the price of paper goes through the roof when candy season comes around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Roasted Pepitas](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Roasted_Pepitas) comes from **carving** a [Pumpkin](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Pumpkin) (which gives you five) as well as **smashing** a carved pumpkin (which gives you an additional five).

While the Pumpkins, Pumpkin Seeds, Pepitas and the recipies stay after Zilloween, the **carve** verb, the Pumpkin Seeds in the Gardening Goods Vendor and the ability to plant them are only available during Zilloween. Any carved Pumpkins, unlit and lit, decompose into Pepitas and Pumpkin Pies after the event.

Zilloween is a holiday that happens every 37th of Remember [every Glitch Year](http://www.glitch.com/calendar/). Since time in Glitch passes six times as fast, and there are 308 days in every Glitch year, the event occurs every 51.3 Earth days. The period of time in which the holiday items are 'active' lasts several real world days.

As to answer the actual question, the best way to get Pepitas off season is simply to ask. Glitch is, ostensibly, a social game, and the players are generally very friendly. Asking on Global, group or even local chat will usually get you someone who is willing to trade or give you the item you need. Supply of items on auction can be finicky, and you often get overcharged for rarer items like Pepitas.

Comment: As an aside, the next Zilloween will happen on the 12/1/2012 at 10am GMT

Answer (score 5):

From the Glitch wiki:

> Roasted Pepitas are a seasonal Food: roasted Pumpkin seeds. They are
>   acquired by carving a Pumpkin, using Knife & Board and a Pick. Carving
>   one Pumpkin gives 5 Roasted Pepitas (and a Carved Pumpkin).
>
> Pumpkins are a tasty seasonal crop. They can only be grown or carved
>   during Zilloween. You can grow these in a crop or a herb garden.
>   Pumpkin Seed is available at Gardening vendors.